# Python script closes after some iterations

Tags: python

I wrote a piece of code and when I run it goes smooth until it gets to 
"czz", I am a beginner and I do not know what is the problem.. If someone could tell me what I am doing wrong. Basically the idea behind this code is to try to find all 3-letters domains available with ".ro"

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import string

from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
from string import ascii_lowercase

f = open('3-letters.txt', 'w')

for x in ascii_lowercase:
    for y in ascii_lowercase:
        for z in ascii_lowercase:
            req = Request("http://"+x+y+z+".ro")

            try:
                response = urlopen(req)
            except HTTPError as e:
                f.write("http://"+x+y+z+".ro\n")
            except URLError as e:
                f.write("http://"+x+y+z+".ro\n")
            else:
                print "bad "+x+y+z


f.close();
```

Comment: is there any error message that you can post?

Comment: Note that this script *does not* check which domain names are available; it only tests which domains have an active website on the default (:80) port. It is quite possible for a domain to be owned but not active. To know which domains are *owned* you would have to refer to the Romanian domain registry whois, which can be found at http://www.rotld.ro/engleza/index_en.html

Comment: Also be aware that the Romanian registrar allows accented (non-ascii) characters in urls!

Comment: Hugh, the idea is that I want to create a txt file with all unregistered domains and what I thought is basically many domains are on :80 port, that`s why I try like this, but if you could give me another suggestion on how to find all of them :)??

Comment: Because I know in this way I will have a lot of domains which are actually not available but I do not know what could be an other way to find those which are available, without checking all 27^3 possibilities :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that you are not closing your connections after you don't need them any longer, you can do that with `response.close()`. Do that in a `finally` block to ensure it will always be executed.

```
try:
    # do stuff
except:
    # do stuff
finally:
    response.close()
```

In addition, here's a better way to generate all the three letter strings than your nested `for` loops:

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> from itertools import product
>>> three_letters = (''.join(x) for x in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3))
>>> for x in three_letters:
...     print(x)

'aaa'
'aab'
'aac'
'aad'
'aae'
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to close the connections.

```
response.close()
```

I hope you are not trying to spam or something.

Comment: I am not spamming, I want to found an organization and I want to choose it`s name depending if I will be able to have a website

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463336/recommended-apis-for-checking-domain-availability

Comment: Yes. I edited the answer. The resource you want to close is response.

Comment: Even with response.close() after the try it doesn`t work

Answer (score 2):

You could try to add a `timeout` argument to `urlopen`:

```
response = urlopen(req, timeout=2)
```

For example, `cze.ro` seems to take forever.